# Applying KeyUp and KeyDown using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JS and need your help with this issue please. I need to apply key-up and key-down using HTML, CSS and JS. I have the original code and I am trying to modify it so I can move through the panel using key-up and key-down, but it does not seem to work at all. Here is a snippet of the original code for the part I am working on:

```js
const P_CONTAINERS_LIST = "containersList";
const P_CONTAINER_EDIT = "containerEdit";
const P_CONTAINER_DELETE = "containerDelete";
Logic.registerPanel(P_CONTAINERS_EDIT, {
  panelSelector: "#edit-containers-panel",

  // This method is called when the object is registered.
  initialize() {
    Logic.addEnterHandler(document.querySelector("#exit-edit-mode-link"), () => {
      Logic.showPanel(P_CONTAINERS_LIST);
    });
  },

  // This method is called when the panel is shown.
  prepare() {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    Logic.identities().forEach(identity => {
      const tr = document.createElement("tr");
      fragment.appendChild(tr);
      tr.classList.add("container-panel-row");
      tr.innerHTML = escaped`
        <td class="userContext-wrapper">
          <div class="userContext-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="usercontext-icon"
              data-identity-icon="${identity.icon}"
              data-identity-color="${identity.color}">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-name truncate-text"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="edit-container pop-button edit-container-icon">
          <img
            src="/img/container-edit.svg"
            class="pop-button-image" />
        </td>
        <td class="remove-container pop-button delete-container-icon">
          <img
            class="pop-button-image"
            src="/img/container-delete.svg"
          />
        </td>`;
      tr.querySelector(".container-name").textContent = identity.name;
      tr.querySelector(".edit-container").setAttribute("title", `Edit ${identity.name} container`);
      tr.querySelector(".remove-container").setAttribute("title", `Remove ${identity.name} container`);

      Logic.addEnterHandler(tr, e => {
        if (e.target.matches(".edit-container-icon") || e.target.parentNode.matches(".edit-container-icon")) {
          Logic.showPanel(P_CONTAINER_EDIT, identity);
        } else if (e.target.matches(".delete-container-icon") || e.target.parentNode.matches(".delete-container-icon")) {
          Logic.showPanel(P_CONTAINER_DELETE, identity);
        }
      });
    });

    const list = document.querySelector("#edit-identities-list");

    list.innerHTML = "";
    list.appendChild(fragment);

    return Promise.resolve(null);
  },
});
```

```html
    <div class="scrollable panel-content" tabindex="-1">
      <table class="unstriped">
        <tbody id="edit-identities-list"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I tried to insert the following part in my JS code, but the problem still exists:

```js
      document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      const selectables = [...document.querySelectorAll("[tabindex='0'], [tabindex='-1']")];
      const element = document.activeElement;
      const index = selectables.indexOf(element) || 0;
      function next() {
        const nextElement = selectables[index + 1];
        if (nextElement) {
          nextElement.focus();
        }
      }
      function previous() {
        const previousElement = selectables[index - 1];
        if (previousElement) {
          previousElement.focus();
        }
      }
      switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 40:
        next();
        break;
      case 38:
        previous();
        break;
      default:
        if ((e.keyCode >= 49 && e.keyCode <= 57) &&
            Logic._currentPanel === "containerEdit") {
          const element = selectables[e.keyCode - 48];
          if (element) {
            element.click();
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    });
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is `Logic` type in your code? what framework are you using or code have you not provided that would make this functional for us?

Comment: also, shouldn't your example have more then 1 `div` with `tabindex` attribute to demo  (or attempt to demo and resolve) the functionality of this?

Comment: you should provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question. That doesn't necessarily mean it has to be functional, but the framework and DOM consideration to such an implementation are important to distinguish on here and in your sample.

Comment: @BrettCaswell thanks for replying, Actually Logic is a const but it is too long so I did not put it here, shall I put the whole definition of const (Logic)?

Comment: Well about the div, it was initially with no tabindex, but I added tabindex = -1.

Comment: not necessarily.. but if it isn't relevant or a known framework, you should consider providing us a sample that doesn't use it.

Comment: No it does not use a known framework , but I also can not replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample seems functional, so I suspect your issue relates to whatever `Logic._currentPanel` is and the concept of `document.activeElement` in that respect.

For `selectables.indexOf(element)` results `-1` when `element` it is out of index or not known, not `null` or `undefined`, so `const index = selectables.indexOf(element) || 0;` won't be `0`;

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const selectables = [...document.querySelectorAll("[tabindex='0'], [tabindex='-1']")];
  const element = document.activeElement;
  const index = selectables.indexOf(element) || 0;

  function next() {
    const nextElement = selectables[index + 1];
    if (nextElement) {
      nextElement.focus();
    }
  }

  function previous() {
    const previousElement = selectables[index - 1];
    if (previousElement) {
      previousElement.focus();
    }
  }
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 40:
      next();
      break;
    case 38:
      previous();
      break;
    default:
      if ((e.keyCode >= 49 && e.keyCode <= 57)) {
        const element = selectables[e.keyCode - 48];
        if (element) {
          element.click();
        }
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display:block;
  padding: 1in;
  border:0.1em solid black;
}

div:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px green;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1">
  1
</div>
<div tabindex="-1">
  2
</div>
```